# Include local .json file in Eclipse Android project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, json

I have a local .json file. I don't want it to be on a server, I just want it to be included in my app. I tried to paste it directly into Eclipse in my project, but I got a FileNotFoundException, I also tried to paste it in the workspace folder in Windows Explorer/Finder and got the same exception. Where should I put it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should put the file either in the `/assets` or `/res/raw` directory of your Android project.  From there, you can retrieve it with either: `Context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename)` or `Context.getResources().getAssets().open("filename")`.

Comment: to further clarify when to use what: use /res/raw when you need a resource ID to be generated for you. Otherwise, you /assets.

Answer (score 9):

Put the json file in assets folder, I have used this method like this

```
public static String jsonToStringFromAssetFolder(String fileName,Context context) throws IOException {
        AssetManager manager = context.getAssets();
        InputStream file = manager.open(fileName);

        byte[] data = new byte[file.available()];
        file.read(data);
        file.close();
        return new String(data);
    }
```

While parsing we can use the method like:

```
String jsondata= jsonToStringFromAssetFolder(your_filename, your_context);
jsonFileToJavaObjectsParsing(jsondata);  // json data to java objects implementation
```

More Info: [Prativa's Blog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109372/include-local-json-file-in-eclipse-android-project/13232128#13232128)

Comment: your answer is very similar to the one in this link http://prativas.wordpress.com/category/android/part-1-retrieving-a-json-file/

Answer (score 4):

Put the file in the assets folder.
You can use the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) open(String fileName) to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Under /assets in your project folder. If you don't have one, make it.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Asset to Local Storage

I had a very similar need. I had a label template file that I needed to provide a Bluetooth printer configuration so I included it in my assets directory and copied it to the internal storage for later use:

```
private static final String LABEL_TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME = "RJ_4030_4x3_labels.bin";

InputStream inputStreamOfLabelTemplate = getAssets().open( LABEL_TEMPLATE_ASSET_PATH );

labelTemplateFile = new File( getFilesDir() + LABEL_TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME );

copyInputStreamToFile( inputStreamOfLabelTemplate, labelTemplateFile );

printer.setCustomPaper( labelTemplateFile.getAbsolutePath() );
```

#### copyInputStreamToFile Function

```
// Copy an InputStream to a File.
//
private void copyInputStreamToFile(InputStream in, File file) {
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=in.read(buf))>0){
            out.write(buf,0,len);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```