# Read local Json data file in Android Wear & Mobile

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wear-os

I have Android *Mobile* + *Wear* Project in Android Studio, I have also added a common module name *Shared*, which is added as dependency by both *Android* and *Wear* modules.

In *Shared* Module (which is simple *Java Library* Module) - I am reading a json data file, located in `src/` & it works fine when i run that particular module (i.e. Shared module). But it cannot find the file in both Mobile & Wear Applications/Modules.

So, My questions are -

1. Is there any way i am able to access/get path of that file, in both Wear & Mobile Modules (like `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pathForDataFile)`)
2. If NO, then what is the best practice in this case.

UPDATE -

I am now retrieving `InputStream` of json data file by accessing Resources from both the modules i.e. *Android + Wear* & creating Object of Classes of Shared Modules using that InputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question? [Include local .json file in Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109372/include-local-json-file-in-eclipse-android-project)

Android Wear is basically a standard Android device, so if you can get it working on the phone, then you can use the same technique on a wearable.

Comment: Actually, I have Cordova project exported from Eclipse & later imported in Android Studio, after that i have added two modules i.e. `Wear` & `Shared`. Now suppose i add my file to `assets` folder then how can i access the same in the `Wear` module. Solution that you mentioned is not working in this case(which i already tried). Any other idea/option to keep that single file at single place and available for both the modules?

Comment: It sounds like you do not want to have to maintain two copies of the same file. On OSX and Linux you can use something called a symbolic link, where you can get the file system to do this for you. When you do ls -al you will then see the file symbolically linked. If you edit this file, the original will change as well. Note that symbolic links do not really work on Windows as easily as on OSX and Linux.

    cd wearable/src/main/assets ; ln -s ../../../../app/src/main/assets/test.file test.file