# Accessing local JSON file using Javascript in Eclipse

Tags: javascript, json, eclipse

Is there a way to locally access .json files using something like:

```
    $.getJSON("example.json", function(example){
    // do something
    });
```

but in Eclipse? I want to use Eclipse because there are java components that already exist in the project and are loaded up in Eclipse. I saw similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109372/include-local-json-file-in-eclipse-android-project) but there seems to only be solutions for Java. I am also very new to Javascript so I'm open to other more elegant solutions as well.

Comment: is the `example.json` in the root or in a specific directory?

Comment: It is in a specific directory

Comment: and when you run the application it is hosted on localhost right? in that case instead of example.json mention the entire file path from the root like `/name_of_directory_containing_the_json/example.json`. Hope it helps

Comment: do the above mentioned changes work?

Comment: I solved my issue using a different approach... but thanks for the comments and advice!

Comment: oh cool nice...